# jQuery on page load event not working

Tags: jquery

I want to my text fade in when page is loaded, i tried with this code-

```
 $(document).on("load", function () {
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
});
```

Why this not working?
I'm using 3.1.1

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not working? To double check that the function is even running, I'd alert something on the page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be passing .on("load") on the `window` instead of the document:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
});
```

Alternatively, you could call .ready() on the document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's working. #div1 { display:none; } was missing also.

Answer (score 4):

Either use `load()`with `window()` or `ready()` with `document()`:-

***All possible examples:-***

```js
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $("#div1").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "div1">this is working!<div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div1").fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div1">this is working!<div>
```

```js
$(window).load(function () {
        $("#div1").fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div1">this is working!<div>
```

```js
$(window).on('load',function () {
        $("#div1").fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div1">this is working!<div>
```

***Note:-***

I have used `fadeOut()` to show you that code is working.

`$(window).load(function ()` does not work in latest versions like jQuery 3.1.1  so use `$(window).on('load',function (){..});`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your code is wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Also, since you are using version 3 of jQuery, the following are supported:

**Internet Explorer: 9+**

**Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari: Current and Current - 1**

**Opera: Current**

**Safari Mobile iOS: 7+**

**Android 4.0+**

If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12

Answer (score 1):

I tested on the snippet.  You can use $(function() { }); instead since jQuery 1.2.3.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Fade in div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the `"load"` on the `window` instead of the `document`

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
});
```

You could also make sure the DOM is ready and the window is loaded

```
// check the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
     // check window is loaded meaning all external assets like images, css, js, etc
     $(window).on("load", function () {
          $("#div1").fadeIn();
     });
});
```

Sometimes the `DOM` can be ready before the `window` is fully loaded due to network connectivity and server response time. And sometimes the `window` can be loaded before the `DOM` is ready if the server is fast and no connectivity issues. But this ensures the `DOM` (document) is ready along with the `window` being fully loaded. If the `window` is loaded before the DOM then when `DOM` is ready the `window` will fire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window in place of document:
Here's [a link](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)!

```
    $( window ).load(function() {
     // Run code
     $("#div1").fadeIn();
    });
```