# How to hide element on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541274/jquery-on-page-load-event-not-working) doesn't fix the problem

I'm using this to hide/show a form field if an option in a menu is selected:

```
function updateView() {
    $('#id_selection').on('change', function (e) {
        const valueSelected = this.value;
        if (valueSelected === 'Value1') {
            $('#id_field').hide();
        } else {
            $('#id_field').show();
        }
    });
}
```

and it works perfectly fine. Now I need the same changes to occur when the page has loaded, so I tried:

```
$('#id_selection').on('change load', function (e) {...}
```

and

```
$('#id_selection').on('change DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {...}
```

and

```
$('#id_selection').on('change ready', function (e) {...}
```

For each, the field is hidden only if the menu selection is changed but nothing happens on page load.

Based on suggestions in the question mentioned above, I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_field").hide();
});
```

which doesn't make any difference, the field remains visible.

Comment: I can not understand the whole issue. But so far what i could understand - If you change the value and then reload the page then these codes will not work. Because then your whole dom will load again and initial value will be selected then . If you want to keep Value1 selected then you can save it in local storage or session storage.

Comment: no need to, I already fixed the issue based on the question that was suggested